# Filter dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to filter by value more than 20

```
ID   value
A    10
B    21
C    22
```

I used `df['ID'] > 20` and received result

```
False
True
True
```

However, I want it to return `B, C`, not boolean value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.loc` is your friend:

```
df.loc[df['value'] > 20, 'ID']
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `eval` of pandas:

```
df.loc[df.eval('value > 20'),'ID']
```

Or (not really recommended), use `where` of pandas:

```
df.where(df['value']>20,df['ID'],axis=1).dropna()['ID']
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine. I'll leave mine up but add a note that explains how this answer does the same thing in a more concise and better way.

Answer (score 0):

Select only rows where value > 20, then return the values of ID

```
import pandas as pd
df = {"ID": ["A", "B", "C"], "val":[10, 21, 22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df[df["val"] > 20]
df["ID"].values
```

Returns:

```
array(['B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

Edit: the answers here using `df.loc` do the same steps as above, only better and in a more concise way. I'll leave this up in case it's explanatory for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to solve here.

You can approach this using a vectorized operation. Right now, your code is only evaluating whether a statement is true or false. By wrapping this statement inside of square brackets, you can filter on your Pandas dataframe where all the statements evaluate to True.

So if your dataset looks like

`df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'value': {0: 10, 1: 21, 2: 22}})`

You can filter on it:
`df[df['value'] > 20]` or if you want to just receive the values in the ID column, you add on that column's name `df[df['value'] > 20]['ID']`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on value

```
df[df['value'] > 20]
```

[image]

You can filter the columns needed by adding the columns needed at the end

```
df[df['value'] > 20].ID
```

[image]